# Parsing flat files using String delimiter "|^|" in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I tried to parse a text file having delimiter as "|^|" using awk command. But awk command is not working as expected.

Below is the example:

*Command-1:*

```
echo "28851|^|178838|^||^|" | awk -F '|^|' '{ print $1}'
```

*Output:*
    28851|^|178838|^||^|

*Expected output:*

```
28851.
```

---

*Command-2:*

```
echo "28851|^|178838|^||^|" | awk -F '|^|' '{ print $2}'
```

*Output:*

```
BLANK or NULL
```

*Expected output:*

```
178838
```

Please provide some inputs on how to parse the text file in Unix.

Answer (score 2):

**Awk** treats `|^|` as a complex regex pattern. But since `|` and `^` are regex metacharacters - they should be escaped with `\` (`\\|\\^\\|`) or put into a character classes `[|][^][|]`.

```
echo "28851|^|178838|^||^|" | awk -F'\\|\\^\\|' '{ print $2 }'
178838
```

Comment: `[^]` doesn't work : `awk: fatal: Unmatched [ or [^` ; it should be `[\\^]` as per [3161993's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46912936/1678362)

Comment: Alright, doesn't always work then ;) What version is it that accepts this syntax? (I'm testing on GNU Awk 4.1.4 myself)

Comment: @Aaron, I'm on `GNU Awk 4.1.3`

Comment: You should use 4 \, 3 leaves one bare, or just use single quotes and use 2 \

Comment: `[^]` without escaping works only for `$1` (in this case) as `^` is the complement in the character class.

Comment: I think `[^][|]` is parsed as the character class that contains every character but `]`, `[` and `|`. `\\^[|]` works just fine, `[^][|]` parses but produces incorrect results and `[^]\\|` fails to parse with "unmatched `[^`"

Comment: [|][^][|] - should not be used, output of "echo "28851|^|178838|^||^|" | awk -F"[|][^][|]" '{ print $2 }'" is blank or null.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '28851|^|178838|^||^|' | awk -F'\\|\\^\\|' '{print $2}'
```

You must escape special characters.